# The response does not come from clicking a button in the bot Telegram by the Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, telegram-bot

The problem is that when the button is pressed in the telegram, no activity comes to the bot controller. Or I do not catch them right. + After clicking bot displays the message "sorry, my bot code is having an issue".

A standard class controller for getting activities on the Microsoft Bot Framework.

```
    [BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity != null && activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new finder_worker());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
            //message.p
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the class that I wrote as an activity handler. It uses HeroCard to create buttons.

```
    [Serializable]
public class finder_worker : IDialog<object>
{
    private const string mark = "sad";
    private const string st_message = "start";
    private const string empty_message = "";

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        //тут их отлавливает
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

    }

    public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = await argument;
            var message_to_send = context.MakeMessage();
            workers.json_worker m = new workers.json_worker(message.ChannelData.ToString());
            await context.PostAsync($"сообщение: {m.message_text}");

            switch (m.message_text)
            {
                case st_message:
                    await context.PostAsync($"инициация знакомства");
                    break;
                case empty_message:
                    await context.PostAsync($"пустое сообщение");
                    break;
                case mark:
                    message_to_send.Attachments.Add(create_button());
                    await context.PostAsync(message_to_send);
                    await context.PostAsync($"тестовое сообщение");
                    //create_button();
                    break;
                default:
                    await context.PostAsync($"прочее сообщение");
                    break;
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"упс... что то не получилось записать на сервер{e.ToString()}");
        }
    }

    public Attachment create_button()
    {

        var card = new HeroCard("Some Text");
        card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button1",
                Type=ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                Value="button1"
            },
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button2",
                Type=ActionTypes.MessageBack,
                Value="button2"
            }
        };

        Attachment cardAttachment = card.ToAttachment();
        return cardAttachment;
    }
}
```

As a test, I send the bot `sad` and wait for the initiation of the buttons. This part goes well. But after clicking the bot does not receive any messages or other activities. I expect to receive a message or other activity that can be processed with Microsoft Bot Framework tools.

Tried:

- specify the type of CardAction as: `MessageBack`, `PostBack`, `ImBack`
- send buttons through `activity.CreateReply`

Thank you!

Comment: Please try to test your bot with another channels and check if the bot work as expected on other channel.

Answer (score 0):

**ActionTypes.MessageBack** is not a valid card action type for telegram (it is for MS Teams).  Please try **PostBack** or **ImBack**

```
public Attachment create_button()
    {

        var card = new HeroCard("Some Text");
        card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
        {
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button1",
                Type=ActionTypes.ImBack,
                Value="button1"
            },
            new CardAction()
            {
                Title = "button2",
                Type=ActionTypes.PostBack,
                Value="button2"
            }
        };

        Attachment cardAttachment = card.ToAttachment();
        return cardAttachment;
    }
```